# How to search excel cell in google and change the order of the cell contents?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to Google search names that are in an Excel cell.

I use =HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/search?q=" & C5,C5).

However the names in the cell have the last name first, then the first name.
How would I swap them around so they appear in google as first name then last name?

Answer (score 0):

### String Modifiers in VBA:

- `Left()` - Takes the left portion of a string up to specified number of characters
  `=Left("DownFall", 4)` Returns "Down"
- `Right()` - same as `Left()` but from the right side
  `=Right("DownFall", 4)` Returns "Fall"
- `Mid()` - Takes a string of characters from the middle of a string (from, number of char)
  `=Mid("DownFall", 3, 4)` Returns "wnFa"
- `find()` - Returns the string position of specified sub string:
  `=Find("F", "DownFall", 1)` Returns "5"
- `TextSplit()` Splits a string into multiple cells:
  `=TextSplit("Down-Fall", "-")` Returns "Down" and in cell 2 "Fall"

*Note: there are many others, but you can accomplish most string manipulations with these few*

### Here is an example of them all together:

[image]

- `=LEFT(C5,FIND(",",C5,1)-1) & " " & MID(C5,FIND(" ",C5,1)+1,250)`

---

[image]

- `=LEFT(C6,FIND(" ",C6,1)-1) & " " & MID(C6,FIND(" ",C6,1)+1,250)`

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If last name is separated from first name with a comma, like this:

Smith, John

Then you can

```
Dim name
name =Split(Cells(row,column).value, ",")
Cells(row, column).value = name(1) & " " & name(0)
```